# ReportViewer 15.0.0 Renerding: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element

Tags: javascript, webforms, reportviewer

I have the following issue with rendering a report(with a certain set of parameters) using MS ReportViewer. The JS invoked from the internal ReportViewer JS code is failing, specifically this section of "ScriptResource.axd":

```
var $addHandlers = Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandlers = function Sys$UI$DomEvent$addHandlers(element, events, handlerOwner, autoRemove) {
    /// <summary locid="M:J#Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandlers" />
    /// <param name="element"></param>
    /// <param name="events" type="Object"></param>
    /// <param name="handlerOwner" optional="true"></param>
    /// <param name="autoRemove" type="Boolean" optional="true"></param>
    var e = Function._validateParams(arguments, [
        {name: "element"},
        {name: "events", type: Object},
        {name: "handlerOwner", optional: true},
        {name: "autoRemove", type: Boolean, optional: true}
    ]);
    if (e) throw e;
    Sys.UI.DomEvent._ensureDomNode(element);
    for (var name in events) {
        var handler = events[name];
        if (typeof(handler) !== 'function') throw Error.invalidOperation(Sys.Res.cantAddNonFunctionhandler);
        if (handlerOwner) {
            handler = Function.createDelegate(handlerOwner, handler);
        }
        $addHandler(element, name, handler, autoRemove || false);
    }
}
```

The "Sys.UI.DomEvent._ensureDomNode(element);" line is failing with the following error:

> Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   element

When I look up the stack trace:

[image]

It appears that the source of this issue is from JS called from the main "Report" page:

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._Splitter, {"HoverStyle":"SplitterHover","ImageCollapse":"/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource\u0026Version=15.0.900.148\u0026Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SplitterHorizCollapse.png","ImageCollapseHover":"/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource\u0026Version=15.0.900.148\u0026Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SplitterHorizCollapseHover.png","ImageExpand":"/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource\u0026Version=15.0.900.148\u0026Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SplitterHorizExpand.png","ImageExpandHover":"/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource\u0026Version=15.0.900.148\u0026Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.SplitterHorizExpandHover.png","ImageId":"ctl00_ApplicationBody_rvReport_ToggleParam_img","IsCollapsable":true,"NormalStyle":"SplitterNormal","Resizable":false,"StoreCollapseField":"ctl00_ApplicationBody_rvReport_ToggleParam_collapse","StorePositionField":"ctl00_ApplicationBody_rvReport_ToggleParam_store","TooltipCollapse":"Hide Parameters","TooltipExpand":"Show Parameters","Vertical":false}, null, null, $get("ctl00_ApplicationBody_rvReport_ToggleParam"));
});
```

This is breaking the rendered report. I'm not sure how to track this down any further, I know that you can get the report to format with different parameters, but I don't understand how one can debug minified JS internal to the ReportViewer library.

Is this JS failure a known issue with certain reports? I am running the latest version of the library(15.0.0). I would post both the report and parameters, however they contain sensitive information. How does one debug issues internal to the ReportViewer library to solve issues such as this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Tricky, I had a C# method running in the MasterPage disabling certain types of control so that the user could not "Edit" the page, looked something like this:

```
//CommonFunctions
public static List<T> GetAllControlsRecursiveByType<T>(ControlCollection Controls) where T : Control
{
    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        if (c is T)
        {
            results.Add((T)c);
        }

        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            results.AddRange(GetAllControlsRecursiveByType<T>(c.Controls));
        }
    }
    return results;
}

public void DisableControls(Control control)
{
    if (control == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    DisableControl(control);
    foreach (System.Web.UI.Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        DisableControl(c);

        // Recurse into child controls.
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            DisableControls(c);
        }
    }
}

foreach (Control element in CommonFunctions.GetAllControlsRecursiveByType<Control>(FindControl("ApplicationBody").Controls))
{
    List<string> excludedIDs = new List<string>() { "btnAjaxDynamicFilterApplyFilter", "btnClose", "btnCancel", "btnExport" };
    List<Type> includedTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(LinkButton), typeof(Button), typeof(ImageButton), typeof(Repeater), typeof(ABC.Controls.ABCRepeater),
        typeof(GridView), typeof(ABC.Controls.ABCGridView), typeof(ABC.Controls.ImageCheckBox) };

    if (!excludedIDs.Contains(element.ID) && includedTypes.Contains(element.GetType()))
    {
        DisableControls(element);
    }
}
```

Turns out this was "Disabling" certain rendered controls within the report viewer, this was in turn breaking the JS in the front end. I fixed this by excluding the "ReportViewer" from this logic:

```
public bool ControlHasParentWithType(Control control, Type type)
{
    if (control == null || control.Parent == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (control.Parent.GetType() == type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return ControlHasParentWithType(control.Parent, type);
}

//Within Method before disabling the control
if (ControlHasParentWithType(element, typeof(ReportViewer)))
{
    continue;
}
```